# Google Sheets Group BY Aggregation functions SUM(K * M) error

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In Google sheets I have 1 sheet with data (Table headings), then I have another sheet where I wish to query certain information.

This is the basic QUERY I am using:

```
select O, SUM(K*M) group by O
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "*" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting: ")"
```

Would this be a issue with the data range that I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets Query() is not able to SUM calculated columns like MYSQL. 
A workaround would need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works (change range to suit)

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:D10, A2:A10*C2:C10}, "select Col2, sum(Col5) group by Col2", 0))
```

Comment: I think this might work with this improvement: `=query({A2:D10, ,ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A10*C2:C10)},"select ...")`

Answer (score 0):

Different interpretation:

```
=query(K:O,"select O, sum(K)+sum(L)+sum(M) group by O")
```

Comment: Your formula would result in a different calculation